How can I jump to the message(s) where an image was shared in Slack?
I sometimes find it convenient to look at all the images I exchanged in a DM:

How can I jump to the message(s) where one of these images was shared in Slack?

To jump to the message(s) where an image was shared in Slack:

Click on  ..., then View file details:


Click on replies:



